# Wrap de uma aplicação

Tags: react

No mundo do react quando eu falo "os componentes que fazem o wrap da aplicação", o que quer dizer isso? O que significa fazer o wrap da aplicação?

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Sua pergunta ficou um pouco vaga, mas fazer um Wrap é colocar a lógica ou os estilos (ou qualquer outra coisa) dentro de um componente que vai resolver tudo isso lá.

Me arrisco a dizer que o Wrapper é o componente inteiro. Por exemplo, digamos que você tem um titulo em todas as páginas de sua aplicação, tipo isso:

```js
<h1 style={{ color: '#f3f3f3', margin: 0, fontSize: '32px' }}>Titulo Top</h1>
```

Como isso vai se repetir em outros páginas, você cria esse componente, fazendo um wrap dele e usa nas outras páginas. Tipo assim:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Title = props => (
  <h1 style={{ color: '#f3f3f3', margin: 0, fontSize: '32px' }}>{props.children}</h1>
);

export default Title;
```

Pronto. Fizemos o Wrap do Titulo e agora você pode usar ele em qualquer página apenas importando ele e dentro do componente usar com `<Title>Meu título</Title>`.

Veja também [este blog](https://blog.matheuscastiglioni.com.br/como-organizar-projetos-em-react/) que usa exatamente o termo que você colocou na dúvida. Lá ele fala sobre Wrap de componentes.

Comment: Não consegui me expressar bem, mas deu para entender o que vc disse. Muito obrigado!

O link do blog está fora do ar.